# All search modes redirect me to search page over and over.

Tags: wordpress, search

The problem: **Every time I try to use any of the search functions (Find contacts, Advanced Search, full-text searh, etc), I fill out the fields, and when I hit "search", it takes me back to the blank search form.**

Background:
We recently changed service providers and hosting for our entire site. At first, it seemed like CiviCRM did not get moved over, I was getting error messages like this: 
[image]

Eventually, the IT service we work through (who arent specific to CiviCRM), got it to this:

[image]

Finally, he decided to instead uninstall and re-install CiviCRM. This worked, except he was then having trouble importing the existing Civi database. At this point the search was working, because I could use "Find Contacts", leave it blank and get two entries (the user doing the installation, and the organization I work for).

I know he has finally been able to import the database, because if I use the corner quicksearch, i can look for  each individual contact, no problem, but trying to get a list of contacts has become impossible.

I've looked through the old forum and previous stack exchange questions but havent found anything. Any help, or pointing in the right direction would be greatly apprecieated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your site is misconfigured at this point.  There should never be a situation where QuickSearch shows more contacts than your other searches.  Based on the initial screenshots, I'd look at the settings in `civicrm.settings.php`.  However, at this point, you should consider hiring a CiviCRM professional to fix the issue - you may want to consider contacting someone from the [CiviCRM Service Providers Association](https://civicrm.org/providers).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'll give him this information and otherwise look through that list to see who might be able to help us.     Otherwise, do you think maybe uninstalling Civi and re-installing and re-loading the database might help? Any suggestions as to where I might find a guide on how to do this?

Comment: Technically, uninstalling/reinstalling Civi would help, because Civi would rewrite `civicrm.settings.php` in the process.  However, I think it makes more sense to go through it manually!  Also, if you DO uninstall/reinstall, you should do it on a test server, so you can review the settings and compare to your live server, it seems like less work than backing up your current setup, blowing it away, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I'll pass on the information to the programmer who is working with us and see what he's comfortable with (I'm a biologist,  just a tech enthusiasts, but this is over my head at the moment!) 

Again,  thank you for your time and expertise.